# OneDrive API upload.createSession returns 400 error when filename is longer than 136 characters

Tags: onedrive

OneDrive APi upload.createSession is throwing a 400 error when the filename is longer than 136 charcters.

The following request is successful.

```
POST /v1.0/drive/items/root:/sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc1.doc:/upload.createSession HTTP/1.1
Host: api.onedrive.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"item":{"name":"sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc1.doc",
         "@name.conflictBehavior":"rename"}}
```

But if you add another character to the filename, (e.g change the extension to docx from doc)

```
POST /v1.0/drive/items/root:/sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc1.docx:/upload.createSession HTTP/1.1
Host: api.onedrive.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {INSERT_TOKEN}
Cache-Control: no-cache

{"item":{"name":"sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc_sample_doc1.docx",
         "@name.conflictBehavior":"rename"}}
```

we get the following response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "invalidRequest",
    "message": "Bad Argument"
  }
}
```

This is irrespective of the depth of the folder you are trying to upload to. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be an arbitrary restriction in the service, and not an issue with how you're making the call. As a result I'm stating this as an answer and not a comment - there's nothing you can do.

We'll track the issue with [the issue you opened](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/458) and further updates will only appear there.

Comment: Thank you. I cross-posted on StackOverflow since the issue was not updated for a couple of days. I will mark this as answer.